# Toggle a div in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can I make a toggle in Angular.JS so a div will open and close when clicked on the same div again. For now it perfoms the action so it opens the div but whenever I click again on it, the div needs to close again.

```
<a ng-href ng-click="openAccordionRow(champion.clean)"> Zerg </a>
```

and this opens:

```
<div ng-show="isAccordionOpen(champion.clean)">
  info
</div>
```

JS:

```
  $scope.activeRows = "";
  $scope.isAccordionOpen = function(row) {
    if ($scope.activeRows === row) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  $scope.openAccordionRow = function(row) {
    $scope.activeRows = row;
  }
```

Problem here is that the same clicked div doesn't close when pressing on it again.

Comment: and why would it? you set it active on click, and you show the active row. clicking on it again isnt going to set it inactive unless you changed your code

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel... Have you consider using like ui-bootstrap: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion

Comment: To add bootstrap for this seems a little bit like a overkill?

Comment: Adding an entire library just to do an open/hide operation is overkill especially if you do not plan to use the other parts of the library. As mkoryak mentions you need to change openAccordionRow to deactivate the row if its already active.

Comment: @Frenck are you using `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your code doesn't have anything that even attempts to collapse the row. You could change your code to this.

**HTML**:

```
<a ng-href ng-click="toggleAccordionRow(champion.clean)"> Zerg </a>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
  $scope.activeRows = "";
  $scope.isAccordionOpen = function(row) {
    if ($scope.activeRows === row) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  $scope.toggleAccordionRow = function(row) {
    $scope.activeRows = $scope.isAccordionOpen(row) ? "" : row;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want toggle. Just use these code.

```
$scope.activeRows = true // Am setting this for default to show
ng-click="$scope.activeRows = !$scope.activeRows" // change ng-click event
ng-show = "$scope.activeRows" // bind directly $scope.activeRows to show.
```

Comment: would only work if there was one collapsible element, but not any more. You changed `activeRows` into to a boolean

Answer (score 0):

the easy way to do such a thing is the way bellow

```
<a ng-href ng-click="hideBar =!hideBar"> Zerg </a>

<div ng-show="hideBar">
  info
</div>
```